# Broken List Cannot be Deleted

Tags: list, delete

Related to [Broken Lists Cannot Be Deleted](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73448/broken-lists-cannot-be-deleted).

How can I accomplish this in Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replicate the same code in a Sandbox solution using Server Object Model. Since the list deletion is a web scoped operation, it should work. If possible design the WebPart to make the code reusable for other broken lists in the same web.